# How can I allow link text to wrap, while ensuring a second link is on the same line as the previous link text?

Tags: html, css

I have a link icon that appears after specific links. If the link text ends at the end of a line, the link icon will sometimes wrap to the next line. How can I ensure that the link icon stays near the text.

```html
lorum ipusm <a href='google.com'>Google dot com</a><a href='/link-info'><img src='link-info.jpg'></a>
```

**what happens:**

lorum ipsum *Google dot com* (**wraps here**)

(icon link)

**what we need to happen**

lorum ipsum *Google dot* (**wraps here**)

*com* (icon link)

Thanks in advance!

Here's a JSfiddle illustrating the issue

I need the `com` to wrap down to the next line and stay with the `(i)`

https://jsfiddle.net/r2k8qc15/

Updated Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/8owqzbdu/2/

I need the icon to be in line with the text, so the link can be in a paragraph.

In my image here, i just added a `<br>` after the `dot` to illustrate how it should work.

[image: link wrapping]

Comment: Please provide screenshots. An image is much better to understand than a person trying to explain one.

Comment: You can edit your snippet and add enough code to demonstrate your issue, a sketch of the desired outut is also needed to fully show what you try to reproduce.

Comment: a smaller width and white-space or, more efficient, `flex` can help https://jsfiddle.net/2h3uv89a/1/

Answer (score 0):

So in trying to throw up a quick jsfiddle of why it didn't work with my icon, i just used `(i)` and noticed it would wrap if there was no space character between the links.

So what i ended up doing was this

```
<a href='#'>link 1</a><a href='#' style='white-space:nowrap!important'>&nbsp;<img src='icon.jpg'></a>
```

So just using `&nbsp;` and `nowrap` to stick that second link to the last word of the first link and pull down the icon with it since i stop it from breaking.